# With CSS, target only part of a reoccurring pattern in a list

Tags: html, css

I have this fragment of a list. It's generated beyond my control and I may only modify the CSS.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class=" menuItem1 first parent"></li>
    <li class=" menuItem2 parent"></li>
    <li class=" menuItem3 parent"></li>
    <li class=" menuItem4 parent selected"> 
        <ul class="nccUlMenuSub1">
            <li class=" menuItem1 first parent"></li>
            <li class=" menuItem2"></li>
            <li class=" menuItem3 selected parent">
                <ul class="nccUlMenuSub2">
                    <li class=" menuItem1 first"></li>
                    <li class=" menuItem2"></li>
                    <li class=" menuItem3"></li>
                    <li class="menuItem4 last"></li>
                    <!-- Even if this pattern continues, I do not want to display it-->
                </ul>
    ... and the list goes on
```

I want to use a `display: none` CSS rule to hide everything except this part of the list from above:

```
            <li class=" menuItem3 selected parent">
                <ul class="nccUlMenuSub2">
                    <li class=" menuItem1 first"></li>
                    <li class=" menuItem2"></li>
                    <li class=" menuItem3"></li>
                    <li class="menuItem4 last"></li>
                    <!-- Even if this pattern continues, I do not want to display it-->
                </ul>
```

The CSS I have developed so far hides all but the first line in my second snippet.

```
.menu .selected ul.nccUlMenuSub1 li[class*="menuItem"]:not(.selected) {
    display: none;
}
```

How might I modify my CSS to allow the element I selected and also two levels of its children (specifically `.nccUlMenuSub2` and its first level of `<li>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide everything but what you are targeting:

```
.menu > li:not(.selected),
.menu > li.selected > ul > li:not(.selected),
.menu > li.selected > ul > li.selected > ul:not(.nccUlMenuSub2),
.menu > li.selected > ul > li.selected > ul.nccUlMenuSub2 ul
{
    display: none;
}
```

This will hide everything except that one tier of `ul.nccU1MenuSub2` and it's direct child `li`s. Any further ul submenus will be hidden, and every sibling to the ul and parent's siblings will be hidden.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1n4fkzbh/)

Comment: Thank you. I'm using your fiddle right now and the first problem I see is that you've selected the first `li.selected` when I need the second and its immediate 2 children.

Comment: @ThisClark It does select exactly what you just described. The second selected is a child of the first, so I can't completely hide the first, or it would hide the second also.

Comment: You're right, and upon reviewing this where I'm actually going to use it, I see I do need this solved in exactly the way you've solved it. Thank you for your help.